# MySQL C# - How to retrieve enum type from MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, enums, casting

I have an enum called ProfileType and in MySQL it is stored as an enum like this:
[image]

The problem is that once I try to login it crashes giving me a "specified cast is not valid" which happens when instatiating the Profile.

```
var cmd = new MySqlCommand($"select * from users where username='{username}' and password='{password}'", connection);
        var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rd.HasRows)
        {
            rd.Read();
            return new Profile
            {
                Username = rd.GetString("username"),
                Email = rd.GetString("email"),
                Password = rd.GetString("password"),
                Picture = rd.GetString("picture"),
                ProfileType = (ProfileType)rd.GetInt16("profileType"),
                AdditionalData = rd.GetString("additionalData")
            };
```

This is the enum:

```
public enum ProfileType
{
    User = 0,
    Library = 1,
    Admin = 2
}
```

I used int to store enum but it was always giving me '0' even if I was signing up as a library.

Comment: What type does `rd.GetFieldType("profileType")` return? SIde notes: you have **dangerous** SQL injection and you should use parameters instead. Also you need to dispose the reader with a `using`. I sincerely hope you are not storing plain-text passwords. Also why bring the password back from the database, seems like another chance for it to be read maliciously?

Comment: @Charlieface yeah, I know about that but I'm trying to make everything work first. rd.GetFieldType("profileType") returns a System.Type and I cannot cast it to ProfileType

Comment: Yes that's what it's supposed to return, just a type object not the actual data, what *is* that type? `rd.GetFieldType("profileType").ToString()`

Comment: it just returns "System.String", I don't know what you're asking me to do sorry. What type do I have to check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MySQL `enum` types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) are actually returned as strings, so you need to parse it

```
ProfileType = Enum.Parse<ProfileType>(rd.GetString("profileType")),
```

Or on older versions of .NET

```
ProfileType = (ProfileType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ProfileType), rd.GetString("profileType")),
```

---

Side notes on your code:

- You have dangerous SQL injection and you should use parameters instead.
- You need to dispose the reader with a `using`.
- I sincerely hope you are not storing plain-text passwords. You should be salt-and-hashing them.
- Why bring the password back from the database, it seems like another chance for it to be read maliciously?
- `if (rd.HasRows)` is unnecessary, you can get that from `rd.Read()`

```cs
using var cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"
select
  username,
  email,
  picture,
  profileType,
  additionalData
from users
where username = @username
  and passwordHash = @passwordHash;
", connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passwordHash", SaltAndHash(password, username));

using var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if(rd.Read())
    return new Profile
    {
        Username = rd.GetString("username"),
        Email = rd.GetString("email"),
        Picture = rd.GetString("picture"),
        ProfileType = Enum.Parse<ProfileType>(rd.GetString("profileType")),
        AdditionalData = rd.GetString("additionalData")
    };
```

Comment: Which version of .NET are you on?

Comment: I'm on 4.0. Just need to update?

Comment: See edit, you can do it the old way with casting. Updating beyond 4.x is a major change (to .NET Core) so depends what else you have going on. If you are using WinForms, or a third party library, then you may break stuff.

Comment: I tried this before telling you but unfortunately it doesn't solve anything. same error

Comment: `(ProfileType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ProfileType), rd.GetString("profileType"))` does not use any generics, how can it be the same error?

Comment: sorry, I intended "specific cast is not valid"

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot reproduce that https://dotnetfiddle.net/S3xPPm

Comment: try instantiating an object that contains ProfileType. That's when I get the error

Comment: Can you construct a https://dotnetfiddle.net showing the issue, because I really can't understand what could be causing this. `ProfileType` is an enum, how could there be an issue instantiating it?

Comment: my bad, I think the real problem is the picture. I forgot I changed it to blob on mysql. That's quite embarassing haha

Comment: I solved it. It was the picture. I changed it to byte[] and then I used a converter. Appreciate your help and sorry for my mistake

Answer (score -1):

Since "rd.GetFieldType("profileType").ToString()" is "System.String", you aren't able to GetInt16 from it.

```
ProfileType = (ProfileType)rd.GetInt16("profileType")
```

-->

```
ProfileType = Enum.Parse<ProfileType>(rd.GetString("profileType"))
```